# Нюансы мультиплексирования каналов

Tags: golang

если я запущу горутину в которой будет select  в бесконечном for, то:
1) получается что если такая горутина будет висеть на процессоре, то КПД нулевой(если никаких событий в каналах не возникает). Верно ли будет сместить эту горутину с ядра через Gosched() в default(конструкция select case)
2) если я эту горутину уберу, внесётся ли она в очередь ожидающих обработки горутин, если в каком то канале этой горутины, вскоре появится событие на обработку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таком куске:

```
var ch1 = make(chan bool)
var ch2 chan bool

go func() {
    t := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    for {
        <-t.C
        ch1 <- true
    }
}()

for {
    select {
    case <-ch1:
        fmt.Println(1)
    case <-ch2:
        fmt.Println(2)
    default:

    }
}
```

загрузка ядра действительно будет 100%. 
происходит это из-за наличия секции default. Если при отсутствии события вам ничего недалть не надо

```
var ch1 = make(chan bool)
var ch2 chan bool

go func() {
    t := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    for {
        <-t.C
        ch1 <- true
    }
}()

for {
    select {
    case <-ch1:
        fmt.Println(1)
    case <-ch2:
        fmt.Println(2)
    }
}
```

И тогда эта горутина будет просто ждать событий в цикле, а при отсутствии событий никакой нагрузки создавать не будет.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, если уберем default, то при отсутствии событий в каналах, горутину постигнет deadlock. Тогда получается, это то что нам и нужно, потому что планировщик Go уберёт эту горутину с ядра. Это верно?

Comment: Это получается то же самое что и в default поставить runtime.Gosched()

Comment: Deadlock там получался из-за того что сообщение приходило только одно и потом больше работать нечему.

Поправил пример.

runtime.Gosched() будет отдавать управление из горутины, но дальше планировщик снова вернет управление в горутину при первой возможности и всё равно это будет 100%я загрузка ядра.

В случае без default горутина просто засыпает пока не получит новое сообщение и ресурсов процессора не занимает.

Answer (score 0):

В default вставьте time.Sleep(time.Millisecond).

Comment: Это костыль, т.к. тогда необоснованно увеличивается среднее время реакции на сообщение до 0.5 милисекунды + немного работы в пустую + писать ещё больше.

Comment: Вы совершенно правы. Эксперимент показал, что time.Sleep в default не только не полезен, но и вреден.